# Android Studio 3.2 build failed with an exception caused by unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: android, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Digital'.
 Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
 Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
     Required by:
         project :
 Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 11s
Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Please add your root `build.gradle` too. Perhaps adding: `maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}` ? Might help

Comment: are you working behind a compay proxy or with network constraints?  can you try to download the needed artefact directly from your browser or using **curl** :  `curl https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom` ?

Comment: Yes I can download it directly from browser, but don't know the path or folder to put the file

Comment: OK will try that @mohsen